# Do PhoneGap Apps need Internet connection?

Tags: android, cordova

I think this is a basic question, but I can't find this on their site, or just correct me if I'm wrong. I would like to ask do phonegap apps need to be connected to the internet for it to be used? I need to understand and know this one. Since I'm torn between two options whether to use the native code or phonegap. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No internet connection is required! :)
U just need to make the normal HTML pages and store them in the asset folder.
See the link how to set up:
http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html

Comment: Is this true even when we are pulling data from a MySql database? and what's the best way to work with dynamic app pages? Use php and get the information in Json format from the database and then use Javascript  to show it in the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can develop PhoneGap applications that run completely offline without internet connection. However, you may synchronize data with an online service if you need to. Ultimately, it depends on your on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Phone Gap can function with and without the internet. With the internet , you can download it. In the absence of internet, you can have fun by creating apps for multiple platform.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap apps can get all of their content from the local device, which means that if you store the assets within the application (the traditional way in PhoneGap is to put pages/images/etc. in teh `assets/www` folder in the Android project), then the app will be able to function offline.